# Get root in binary tree without root variable

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

My Node class only has .left and .right, I cannot have a root variable. In this case, how can I get the root of the binary tree?

```
private int data;
        private Node rightChild;
        private Node leftChild;
```

Comment: How does the node look like? is there previous/parent?

Comment: The code I pasted is how the Node looks like

Comment: Oh then it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

Each node in the binary tree only holds the pointer to its children, not its parents. So if you have one `Node` object from somewhere in the path, you can only acquire its successors, not its predecessors.

Brief example: Imagine the following binary tree (unbalanced, not sorted):

```
    2
  /   \
 7     5


Node(2): L: Node(7), R: Node(5)
Node(7): L: null, R: null
Node(5): L: null, R: null
```

In order to get the parent of each node, you'd have to store a pointer to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the root as part of every node, instead, you can create a Node and set it as the root and pass that Node to your tree building function. The tree building function can take in the root, and the value to be inserted.

Following example will follow the Binary Search Tree rules during the build

1. if the new node’s value is lower than the current node’s, go to the
   left child
2. if the new node’s value is greater than the current node’s, go to
   the right child
   when the current node is null, we’ve reached a leaf node, we insert the new node in that position

```
public class Tree {
    static class Node {
        int value;
        Node left, right;

        Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }

    public void insert(Node node, int value) {
        if (value < node.value) {
            if (node.left != null) {
                insert(node.left, value);
            } else {
                System.out.println(" Inserted " + value + " to left of " + node.value);
                node.left = new Node(value);
            }
        } else if (value > node.value) {
            if (node.right != null) {
                insert(node.right, value);
            } else {
                System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to right of " +
                    node.value);
                node.right = new Node(value);
            }
        }
    }
    public void traverseInOrder(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            traverseInOrder(node.left);
            System.out.print(" " + node.value);
            traverseInOrder(node.right);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Tree tree = new Tree();
        Node root = new Node(5);
        System.out.println("Binary Tree Example");
        System.out.println("Building tree with root value " + root.value);
        tree.insert(root, 2);
        tree.insert(root, 4);
        tree.insert(root, 8);
        tree.insert(root, 6);
        tree.insert(root, 7);
        tree.insert(root, 3);
        tree.insert(root, 9);
        System.out.println("Traversing tree in order");
        tree.traverseInOrder(root);

    }
}
```

Comment: For your traverseInOrder. Why is your argument in main empty?

Comment: my bad, I'd paid more attention to the tree building part, missed the display part